# Deconvolution problem to solve with Moffat PSF (Point Spread function) for atmospheric effects

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, deconvolution

I have to do an exercise about the large deconvolution problem in astrophysics. First, we use the Moffat PSF to model atmospheric effects. Here's its expression :

[image]

I have generated a starting image from this PSF, but with adding white noise noise and background, like this :

[image]

Here's an example of starting image (30x30 pixels) :

[image]

Now, we consider the location of star and PSF parameters (r0,c0,alpha,beta) are known.

I have to answer to these questions :

[image]

For the first question, I am looking for the estimation of amplitude "`a"` of PSF and of value of background "`b`". I have to formulate the expression (1) under matricial form with **a known matrix H** and a set of data "d" (It seems that "d" array is the vector 1D expression of image 2D : `d = D(:); and D = reshape(d,Rows,Columns)`.

So my question is : What is this expression with "**known matrix H**" ? I can't find in my courses this matricial expression that could allow to estimate the amplitude "`a`" of star and the estimation of "background" "`b`" ?

Which **H known matrix** is considered into this problem ?

Comment: I assume the point is that you dont specify the matrix `H`. Assume it is known, and do the exercise by never explicitly writing it out.

Comment: Could you plot the following three images next to each other (1) your current starting image (2) an image of the PSF (which is a known function of r and c) (3) a homogeneous gray image. What you are looking for is the coefficients in the linear combination image1 = a image2 + b image3. You do this by placing this equation for each of the 400 pixels in columns (such that you can express it as a matrix equation).

Comment: Also, maybe you should not forget to mention that you posted a very similar question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375713/likelihood-difference-between-deducing-original-signal-and-deducing-parameters